# I am getting the following error need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python

I have the following structure in python.

```
data_set = {'1':[('Worktype', 'Consultancy'), ('Age', 30), ('Qualification', 'Ph.D'), ('Age', 9)], \
            '2':[('Worktype', 'Service'), ('Age', 21), ('Qualification', 'M.Tech'), ('Age', 1)], \
            '3':[('Worktype', 'Research'), ('Age', 26), ('Qualification', 'M.Tech'), ('Age', 2)], \
           }
```

I am using the following loop to access the elements. My aim is to print the value associated with 'Worktype'.

```
for d,c in data_set:
    print(c['Worktype'])
```

However, I am getting the following error -

```
for d,c in data_set:
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

What  is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you iterate over a dictionary directly, it only iterates over its `key`s . To iterate over the values as well, you should iterate over `.items()` , even then the inner elements are lists, not `dict`, so you cannot directly access - `c['Worktype']` .

Seems like the inner elements were meant to be a dictionary, if so, you should first convert them into dictionary, by using the `dict()` built-in function. Example -

```
data_set = {k:dict(v) for k,v in data_set.items()}
for d,c in data_set.items():
    print(c['Worktype'])
```

Demo -

```
>>> data_set = {'1':[('Worktype', 'Consultancy'), ('Age', 30), ('Qualification', 'Ph.D'), ('Age', 9)], \
...             '2':[('Worktype', 'Service'), ('Age', 21), ('Qualification', 'M.Tech'), ('Age', 1)], \
...             '3':[('Worktype', 'Research'), ('Age', 26), ('Qualification', 'M.Tech'), ('Age', 2)], \
...            }
>>>
>>> data_set = {k:dict(v) for k,v in data_set.items()}
>>>
>>> for d,c in data_set.items():
...     print(c['Worktype'])
...
Service
Consultancy
Research
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two errors. First, you're iterating incorrectly over the key/value pairs (use `items()` for that). Second, the values are not dictionaries, they're lists of key/value pairs - which can be easily turned into a dictionary using `dict()`. Try this:

```
for d, c in data_set.items():
    print(dict(c)['Worktype'])
```

My approach has the advantage of leaving unmodified the original data set. Now the above will print:

```
Consultancy
Research
Service
```

Comment: Also note that the OP's variable `c` will not be a `dict` but instead it will be a `list` so that will cause a problem too.